# Update Object at Specific Array Index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection of the form

```
{ id : 1,
  data: [ [ { name : "alice" }, { name : "bob" } ],
          [ { name : "dan" },   { name : "rob" } ] ] }
```

and the structure of the array has meaning. How would I update the first element ([0][0]) and set name = "alex". I've seen many questions addressing how to update array elements that match a query but not specific elements. To be clear, after the update, the record should look like this:

```
{ id : 1,
  data: [ [ { name : "alex" },  { name : "bob" } ],
          [ { name : "dan" },   { name : "rob" } ] ] }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming, you have created the structure with some purpose, which ideally becomes tougher to query, you could update it by specifying the index explicitly:

```
db.collection.update({"id":1},{$set:{"data.0.0.name":"alex"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

If we don't have a fixed position and is known at runtime or Dynamic 
then this approach works perfectly

```
var setObject = {};
setObject["board."+ x +"."+ y] = player;
gamesColl.update({_id: realId},{
$set:setObject
}, function(err,doc){
console.log(err,doc);
});
```

Comment: This one approach works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can go further!!
if you want to paste indexes as a variable use string template like this

```
db.collection.update({"id":1},{$set:{[`data.${index}.${index}.name`]:"alex"}})
```